# JasperReportServer 5.5 sample tutorial

Tags: jasperserver

I'm trying to start the jasper report server connecting to my oracle db . But i'm getting timezone mismatch exception while connection to the oracle DB. I know this happening because local pc time and db server time difference.

Can anyone help me with a good tutorial on Jasper report server .Can i start the server without connecting to a DB or can you help me how to configure it to H2 database.. Please

Answer (score 1):

Here is the guide you can start with

http://jasperserver.sourceforge.net/docs/3-5-0/JasperServer-User-Guide.pdf
[image]

In the screenshot I have depicted how to change the timezone and local even before logging in the Jasperserver.

Hope that it helps.